# How an I2c read as well as write operation in "handler function" of request_threaded_irq affects the driver as a whole.?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, irq

I have a driver code with handler function and thread function of request_threaded_irq similar to this:

```
irq-handler fn()
{
      /*disable device interrupt*/
      i2c read from register;
      set disable bit to client-device-interrupt 
      i2c write back;
      return IRQ_WAKe_THREAD;
}



irq-thread fn()
{
      i2c read from register;
      ....
      ....
      /*enable device interrupt*/
      i2c read from register;
      set enable bit to client-device-interrupt 
      i2c write back;
      /*Rest of the operation*/
      ..........
      ..........
      return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

I have few question with respect to above implentation.

1. Will 2 i2c operation in "handler fn" takes considerable amount of time.?
2. Should I need to make bit manipulation in "handler fn" atomic?
3. Should I move the operation performed till "enable device interrupt" from "thread fn" to "handler fn"(this would cost me 4 more i2c operation and one bit manipulation exactly) ? - reason being chances are there that i can miss interrupt as per above code implementation.
4. If I do so(as per question 3). how does it affects the other device interrupts.(**as I have a basic doubt whether "handler fn" in hard IRQ context operates with interrupts disabled**)

Please provide me a good and optimum solution for the above scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your irq-handler pseudo-code and irq-thread pseudo-code.  If your handler is waking a thread, then it shouldn't be talking to the hardware at all.  Also, are you bit-banging gpio pins or do you have i2c controllers?

Comment: Yes, I am using Bit banging.
Actually, I am not good at writing IRQ handler,
But, What is my need is, When an Interrupt happens,
1. I need to disable interrupt in i2c client device(Read the ctrl reg disable interrupt mask/status bit) in handler
2. After disabling I wanted to do further operations : Reading interrupt status register of client device and process it in "Thread function". 

Request you to provide me optimum solution to do so, that I won't miss interrupt as well as pretty fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I2C read/write transfers are NOT deterministic.

The protocol allows peripheral slave ICs to perform [clock stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Clock_stretching_using_SCL) thereby allowing them to "hold" the master until they are ready. 
However this is NOT a common scenario and hence each I2C transfer usually completes in a pre-determined interval most of the time. However, it is NOT a guarantee, and hence NOT a good idea to perform several I2C transfers within an ISR.

This [**link**](http://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2011-March/001118.html) contains a nice explanation about the fundamentals of threaded irqs and their proper usage.

---

#### Optimal design for the above scenario ?

Using threaded-interrupt handler approach will not have many benefits as attempting to enable/disable the interrupts on the device will add to the latency.

In your current scenario (single interrupt from single device), one can stick to the regular `request_irq()` to register an interrupt service routine(ISR).

**ISR** code :
1. In the ISR, call `disable_irq()` to prevent further interrupts.
2. Schedule a bottom half handler function (workqueue is a good choice).
3. Return `IRQ_HANDLED` from the ISR.

**Bottom-half handler** code :
4. Perform I2C transfers.
5. Call `enable_irq()` and exit.

---

**NOTE** :
Another way to implement the same design would be to use a **threaded-irq without an ISR**. This achieves the same as the above design and eliminates the need to define/initialise/cleanup the bottom-half handler separately in your code.

In [**this approach one**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/touchscreen/qt602240_ts.c?v=2.6.38#L1283) would put all the I2C read/write code within the **[IRQ thread function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/touchscreen/qt602240_ts.c?v=2.6.38#L677)** and pass it to `request_threaded_irq()` along-with `handler = NULL` i.e. an empty ISR.

Comment: But With workqueue as bottom half, Probability of missing device interrupts is high I guess !?

Comment: For higher priorities one can use the **threaded-irq without an ISR** approach. Alternately one can tweak the thread priorities as well. How fast does the device generate interrupts? You are developing a driver for which device?...

Comment: Actually I am working on a i2c device (bit banging driver), which interrupts application processor on attach/detach events. actaully I have implemented in threaded-irq without ISR. With that it is working fine except for debounce errors. I wanted to try writing an ISR firstly to address debounce error and secondly out of interest.