# why do we need bottom halves in keyboard drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am aware that bottom halves are mainly targeted for activities which takes long time.
I have seen references of bottom halves in key board drivers like adp5588-keys.c/atkbd.c/matrix-keypad.c etc.Please can any one help me to understand why do we need bottom halves in key boad like drivers where its functionality is to capture a key evnts(mainly) .

from adp5588-keys.c:

from Probe:

```
INIT_DELAYED_WORK(&kpad->work, adp5588_work);
```

from Irq:

```
static irqreturn_t adp5588_irq(int irq, void *handle)
{
struct adp5588_kpad *kpad = handle;

/*
* use keventd context to read the event fifo registers
* Schedule readout at least 25ms after notification for
* REVID < 4
*/

schedule_delayed_work(&kpad->work, kpad->delay);

return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

bottom half:

```
static void adp5588_work(struct work_struct *work)
{
struct adp5588_kpad *kpad = container_of(work,
struct adp5588_kpad, work.work);
struct i2c_client *client = kpad->client;
int status, ev_cnt;

status = adp5588_read(client, INT_STAT);

if (status & ADP5588_OVR_FLOW_INT)  /* Unlikely and should never happen */
dev_err(&client->dev, "Event Overflow Error\n");

if (status & ADP5588_KE_INT) {
ev_cnt = adp5588_read(client, KEY_LCK_EC_STAT) & ADP5588_KEC;
if (ev_cnt) {
adp5588_report_events(kpad, ev_cnt);
input_sync(kpad->input);
}
}
adp5588_write(client, INT_STAT, status); /* Status is W1C */
}
```

BR,
& Sridhar

Comment: bottom halves are being used here considering some events like copying big amount of data(CTRL+C) ???

Comment: I suspect it's mostly done to avoid i2c transfers in the interrupt handler - the adp5588_read/adp5588_write uses i2c to communicate with the keyboard. (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921933/how-an-i2c-read-as-well-as-write-operation-in-handler-function-of-request-thre) why that might be a bad ide.

Comment: From the comment before the `schedule_delayed_work`, it sounds like early revisions of this device may have not had the key events available immediately upon IRQ, thus requiring the read to happen at least 25ms later.

Comment: What if you are playing a game, (using ab input device) sending in large amount of data frequently, without bottom halves the interrupt handlers would have too much work to do which could potentially lead some key being handled to be missed. Also, the command/key received through the interrupt may be small itself, but may require doing a lot of work to be done, which would be ideal to be delayed and handled using bottom halves.

Comment: The comment `Schedule readout at least 25ms after notification` suggests there might be a hardware restriction that requires reading after 25ms on some models. Obviously you wouldn't want to be sleeping in an interrupt handler so you schedule it away.